# Can you recover from overwriting a file in git during Visual Studio sync?

Tags: git, visual-studio

So, I have commits on my local master, which are not pushed to the main master.

I sync the project and pull changes that are on the main master, but there is a merge conflict.

No problem, I say, I know the reason because we changed the same line so we could get it working...I'll just take his copy...doh!

The main master didn't have my commits and now there is no history of them..at all.....or maybe there is somehow, does anyone know?

Or maybe there should be a history, meaning something else would have happened (as my memory is rusty).

Many thanks

Ian

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting confused is that you have resolved the conflict by taking remote changes and not yours. Thus you have lost all your changes.

If you have already finished merging and committed.. start fresh by doing the following.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

The above Will remove your merge commit and take you back to the state before your merge

```
git pull origin master
```

Then you will get the merge conflict again. Just resolve them manually instead of taking remote copy. This should solve your problem

Comment: @Kieky As a precautionary measure, just quit  and save your visual-studio changes before you do the above. I have seen it save the *.vcproj , *.sln , *.vcproj.filters file only when you quit it.

Comment: Thanks Abdus, so you think they're still there from before the merge? There have been quite a few commits and merges with head since this happened, so would your suggestion still work?

Comment: @Kieky In the case you have more commits after your merge, my suggestion is git checkout the commit before the merge happened. Create a separate branch from that commit ( git checkout -b temp ). On the temp branch do git pull origin master and resolve the conflicts correctly. Then merge temp to your master locally. I hope that would help